# What is the advantage of using (it != vector.end()) instead of (it < vector.end()) in for loops?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I often see this:

```
for ( auto it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it ) { ... }
```

while I think that this should be more safe when iterating through a vector:

```
for ( auto it = vector.begin(); it < vector.end(); ++it ) { ... }
```

Especially when items in the vector are deleted or there are jumps etc.

What is the advantage of the first over the second? Why not only use the second?

Edit: When looking at the "duplicate question"'s answer it is more generic for any list to use "!=" instead of "<". But I don't see the advantage for **vectors** specifically.

**Case**: You iterate through the vector, and delete some items (filter for example). The very last item is deleted, this means your iterator now points to vector.end(), before the for loop checks, your iterator is incremented, thus `it = vector.end() + 1` and `(it != vector.end()) == true`, so the loop continues.

Comment: In response to your edit, please take the time to read and carefully study the _whole_ linked page, not just tidbits. The accepted answer says: _"if you end up in a scenario where `it != foo.end()` does not do the same thing as `it < foo.end()`, you already have undefined behavior because you've iterated past the end of the range"_ i.e. there is literally no benefit in switching to `<`, and you've lost the genericity for nothing.

Comment: I have added a case to explain when this is not the case and why I initially started to question the "!=" practice

Comment: Your addition changes nothing. Refer again to my previous comment, and to the detailed explanations on the linked page. Your loop doesn't continue, your loop is _broken_ due to undefined behaviour. Changing from `!=` to `<` doesn't solve that; the program still has undefined behaviour. Instead of tinkering with operators, fix the broken logic!!

Comment: Your change only describes an undefined behavior. Erasing items from vector invalidates the Iterators, pointers and references pointing to deletion position and beyond. So your it is becoming invalid not vector.end() in described situation.

Comment: The erase returns the iterator to the next item or .end() that is not undefined. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase see return value

Comment: Don't blindly stick `++it` in loops that erase. The body of the loop has to do the proper advancing. Alternately use `std::remove(_if)`